# matching every row of a dataset against all rows of a second dataset iteratively

Tags: r, loops, debugging, apply, tidyverse

I have two datasets and named E and eF respectively.

```
E<-dput(A%>%head(n=6) %>% select(Inception_Date,Name))        
structure(list(Inception_Date = structure(c(962323200, 962323200, 
810950400, 988675200, 1042502400, 1536624000), tzone = "UTC", class =  
c("POSIXct","POSIXt")), Name = c("Calvert Social Index B", "Calvert US   
Large Cap Core Rspnb Idx A", "Green Century Equity Individual 
Investor", "Praxis Value Index A", "Vanguard FTSE Social Index I", 
"Amundi IS Amundi MSCI USA SRI ETF DR")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

eF<-dput(B%>%head(n=8) %>% select(Inception_Date,Name))
structure(list(Inception_Date = structure(c(760233600, 519868800, 
1380067200, 1101772800, 1325203200, 628473600, 1325203200, 1123804800
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Name = c("Amana     
Growth Investor", "Amana Income Investor", "Amana Income   
Institutional", "American Century Sustainable Equity A", 
"Ariel Appreciation Institutional", "Ariel Appreciation Investor", 
"Ariel Focus Institutional", "Baywood Socially Responsible Invs"
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I need to subtract every inception date of eF by the first inception date of E, if the difference between the dates are between -1500 days and +1500 days, for example, if the difference in date is between + or - 1500 days, I will select them, and make a dataset for the data with dates satisfy the criteria.

But I need to then subtract every date of eF by the second date of E, and use the same criteria to select according to the same criteria and then create a new file.

Then I will need to subtract every number of eF by the 3rd, 4th date of E, etc, and match, select them according to the same criteria.

I should have ***8 output .csv files***.

I used the following code, would you please debug for me, please?

```
for (k in 1:nrow(E)) {
F_temp <- eF;
G_temp <- F_temp %>% filter(abs(F_temp$Inception_Date-    
E$Inception_Date[k]) <= 1500);
print(G_temp)}
for(i in 1:nrow(G_temp)){
write.csv(G_temp, paste0("test", i, ".csv"), row.names = TRUE)
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind sharing some data? Then we can reproduce the error and it is easier to help you.

Comment: how to send excel files? thanks! @yannik Suhre

Comment: I don't know how to send excel files. But if we have 5 dates in file A and 5 dates in file B, each time i need to find the difference of all dates in file B against a row in file A. Then I need to find the difference of dates of all rows against the second, third, fourth row, iteratively.

Comment: just do ```dput(head(A))``` and add the data from the console to your question.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I guess what you are looking for, is the following:

```r
A <- c(7,6,5,4,3,6,0,8,19,42,-4,59)
B <- c(9,-10, 8, 4,-2,6,7,9,18)

C <- as.data.frame(sapply(B, `-`, A))
```

This command (`sapply()`) will return you a matrix (which I convert using `as.data.frame` to a data.frame), where each row represents the subtraction of one Element from B for the whole Vector of A.

Comment: I do not know whether SO has a chat function, but go ahead. However, if you have any further questions, please update your question. And, please accept my answer if it helped you! ;)

Comment: Hi Yannik, I have modified my question to be more specific. Thank you @Yannik Suhre